# Ingresar múltiples datos(numeros) y obtener una sola lista?

Tags: python

En la practica de este programa para calcular la varianza de unos datos, ¿es posible que en la entrada de `input()` se puedan introducir múltiples números, y obtener una única lista?

Por ejemplo que el usuario introduzca

```
20 24 26 23 23
```

y obtener una lista

```
[20, 24, 26, 23, 23]
```

¿es posible esto ?

```
class Varianza(object):
    """docstring for Varianza"""
    datos = [0]
    media = []
    eleva = []
    total = []
    mivar = []
    def __init__(self, media, eleva, total, mivar):
        pass

    def medi(self):
        for num in self.datos:
            num = int(input('Dime los numeros: '))
            if num > 0:
                self.datos.append(num)
                self.media = sum(self.datos) / len(self.datos)
                self.eleva = (num - self.media) ** 2
                self.total.append(round(self.eleva))
                self.mivar = sum(self.total) / (len(self.datos) - 1)
            print(self.datos)
            print(self.media)
            print(self.eleva)
            print(sum(self.total))
            print(self.mivar)

estadistica = Varianza('', '', '', '')
estadistica.medi()
```

El programa funciona con el código como lo tengo (esta es la consola), pero lo que yo quiero es introducir todos los números a la vez, para consultar esos datos;

```
Dime los numeros: 25
[0, 25]
12.5
156.25
156
156.0
Dime los numeros: 26
[0, 25, 26]
17.0
81.0
237
118.5
Dime los numeros: 13
[0, 25, 26, 13]
16.0
9.0
246
82.0
Dime los numeros: 23
[0, 25, 26, 13, 23]
17.4
31.360000000000017
277
69.25
Dime los numeros:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por supuesto que puedes, debes reescribir el método `medi`. La siguiente es una forma sencilla sin cambiar mucho del código existente:

```
  def medi(self):

      numeros = input('Dime los numeros: ')
      for num in [int(n) for n in numeros.split(" ")]:

          if num > 0:
              self.datos.append(num)
              self.media = sum(self.datos) / len(self.datos)
              self.eleva = (num - self.media) ** 2
              self.total.append(round(self.eleva))
              self.mivar = sum(self.total) / (len(self.datos) - 1)

          print(self.datos)
          print(self.media)
          print(self.eleva)
          print(sum(self.total))
          print(self.mivar)
```

Básicamente:

- En números obtenemos del usuario una cadena con números separados por espacios, es importante definir y respetar el separador de los datos
- Luego aciendo `[int(n) for n in numeros.split(" ")]` simplemente generamos una  lista producto del `split()` de la cadena del usuario `numeros` en cada número en particular.

Answer (score 0):

sugiero que ingreses los datos separados por algun caracter separador (puede ser una coma, un espacio depende de ti) por ejemplo si ingresas:
25,4,8,58 la función input() nos devolverá una cadena asi '25,4,8,58', esta cadena la puedes separar mediante la función split el cual devuelve una lista con los elementos que estan separados en este caso por la coma, a esta lista la puedes convertir en numero usando el operador int a toda la lista, finalmente lo conviertes en lista.

ejemplo:

```
datos = list(map(int, input().split(',')))
print(datos)
```

espero que te sirva

Comment: por qué pusiste un int, al principio?

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar algo así:

```
from statistics import variance
datos_crudos = input('Dime los numeros: ')
lista_datos = [float(d) for d in datos_crudos.split()]
print(variance(lista_datos))
```

- En la primera línea importamos la función `statistics` para utilizar la función `variance` para calcular la varianza.
- Luego guardamos los datos recibidos en la variable `datos_crudos`. Lo números ingresados deben estar separados por espacio.
- A `datos_crudos` lo convertirmos en una lista con el método `split` utilizando el separador por defecto (espacio). Después cada dato de la lista se cambia a tipo `float` mediante una comprensión de lista.
- Finalmente se imprime la varianza